# Get all values of same key and user-id as php array (SQL)

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have the following sql structure

```
user-id  |  meta_key  |  meta_value
-------------------------------
1        |  car       |  mercedes
2        |  hotel     |  meridia
2        |  street    |  hillsroad
2        |  car       |  audi
1        |  car       |  ford
```

I want to get **all** "`car models (values)`" **as one php array per user**:

```
$cars = array(mercedes, ford); // data should look like this
```

With the following sql request I just get one result:

```
$cars = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT car FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = '.$user->ID);
```

Comment: SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'car'

Comment: Why are you selecting records only for one specific user id, when the data you want to get is associated with multiple different user ids?

Comment: Sry, I updated the infos. I want "all car models per user".

Comment: _"With the following sql request I just get one result"_ - that makes no sense; you _should_ only be getting an error. The `wp_usermeta` table does not have a _column_ named `car`.

Comment: Damn, you are right, its really too hot here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A)` like the [manual](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/) shows

```
$cars = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = '.$user->ID.' AND meta_key = "car"', ARRAY_A);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, big thx! Also for the info link.